# Object code and procedurale code

Tags: python, object

As i'm still a noob coder in python, I'm at a point where i want to know the difference between code structure. Object or Procedural

Here is my current code for a class which handle mysql connect and querying

```
import pymysql

class Database(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.db = pymysql.connect(host="localhost",    # your host, usually localhost
                                  user="root",         # your username
                                  passwd="",  # your password
                                  db="mgdeal")        # name of the data base
        self.cur = self.db.cursor()

    def select(self, sql):
        cursor = self.db.cursor()
        cursor.execute(sql)
        result = cursor.fetchall()
        cursor.close()
        return result

    def insert (self, sql):
        cursor= self.db.cursor()
        cursor.execute(sql)
        newID = cursor.lastrowid
        cursor.close()
        return newID


if __name__ == '__main__':
    db = Database()
```

Now i have found and understand this new mysql class

```
class MysqlPython(object):
    """
        Python Class for connecting  with MySQL server and accelerate development project using MySQL
        Extremely easy to learn and use, friendly construction.
    """

    __instance   = None
    __host       = None
    __user       = None
    __password   = None
    __database   = None
    __session    = None
    __connection = None

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if not cls.__instance or not cls.__database:
             cls.__instance = super(MysqlPython, cls).__new__(cls,*args,**kwargs)
        return cls.__instance
    ## End def __new__

    def __init__(self, host='localhost', user='root', password='', database=''):
        self.__host     = host
        self.__user     = user
        self.__password = password
        self.__database = database
    ## End def __init__

    def __open(self):
        try:
            cnx = MySQLdb.connect(self.__host, self.__user, self.__password, self.__database)
            self.__connection = cnx
            self.__session    = cnx.cursor()
        except MySQLdb.Error as e:
            print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0],e.args[1])

    def __close(self):
        self.__session.close()
        self.__connection.close()

    def select(self, table, where=None, *args, **kwargs):
        result = None
        query = 'SELECT '
        keys = args
        values = tuple(kwargs.values())
        l = len(keys) - 1

        for i, key in enumerate(keys):
            query += "`"+key+"`"
            if i < l:
                query += ","
        ## End for keys

        query += 'FROM `%s`' % table

        if where:
            query += " WHERE %s" % where
        print(query)
        ## End if where
```

This 2 class can be used inside this main program:

```
emailFieldID = "Login"
passFieldID = "Password"
loginButtonXpath = "//*[@id='id_1__']"
headerFieldID = "header"

emailFieldElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_id(emailFieldID))
passFieldElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_id(passFieldID))
loginButtonElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath(loginButtonXpath))

# Envoie des credentials
emailFieldElement.clear()
emailFieldElement.send_keys(Username)
passFieldElement.clear()
passFieldElement.send_keys(Password)
loginButtonElement.click()

# Etape 2: Ajout des produit

#Initialisation de l'objet Database
db = Database()


sql = 'SELECT * FROM `table 2` WHERE `categorie` = "Lego"'


listeproduit = db.select(sql)


for record in listeproduit:

    skuref     = record[0]
    print (skuref)
    ean        = record[1]
    titre_prod = record[2]
    print (titre_prod)
    desc_prod  = record[7]
    img_prod   = record[6]
    cat1       = record[11]
    cat2       = record[12]
    cat3       = record[13]
    cat4       = record[14]
    marque     = record[12]
```

I wanted to know which of this 2 class are more object oriented ?
As far as i understand object code is always when make an instace object from a class but for me it looks like more a way of storing function objet inside super function...i want to know when we can say it's object or not...

Also inside my main program, what must be changed to say it's objet code?

Thanks for you help.